# PasteWSGI server is not accepting POST data properly.

Tags: python-2.7, paster

I have a PasteWSGI server running.

Here is the sample curl request,

```
curl -vX POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/save_topology --data '{"topo" : {"A": "asdasdasd"}, "house_id" : "2"}'
```

server side code snippet is,

```
  def save_topology(self):
    from plotwatt.topology import save

    print request.POST

    topo = request.params.get('topo')
    house_id = request.params.get('house_id')

    return 'OK'
```

logs,

```
MultiDict([(u'{"topo" : {"A": "asdasdasd"}, "house_id" : "2"}', u'')])
```

My question is how can i access passed json as it is in server?

Server details :

```
Server: PasteWSGIServer/0.5 Python/2.7.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.
I needed json data being sent over the wire as it is. I have done something like this,

```
data = json.loads(urllib.unquote_plus(request.body.strip('=')))
```

request.body contains the actual data.

You may like to go through API reference http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html#request